# Multiple MVCContrib Grid on 1 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib-grid

I have multiple mvccontrib grids on 1 view page each w/ its own pagination. My problem is when I page 1 grid it pages the other 2 as well. Is there I can differentiate what grid is being called so only the 1 gets paged or are there any other work around for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `page` query string parameter to different values on both grids:

```
@Html.Pager(Model.Collection1).QueryParam("page1")
@Html.Pager(Model.Collection2).QueryParam("page2")
```

or build the query string yourself:

```
@Html.Pager(Model.Collection1).Link(page => Html.ActionLink(page, "SomeAction", new { page1 = page, page2 = Request["page2"] }))
@Html.Pager(Model.Collection2).Link(page => Html.ActionLink(page, "SomeAction", new { page1 = Request["page1"], page2 = page }))
```